# jQuery dropdown menu

Tags: jquery

I have a navbar, a ul with the id of menu that I want to turn into a dropdown menu.  There are uls in each li, and each ul has the class sublist, which in the CSS has a display value of none, but with the jQuery below even though I hover over it, the ul won't show.  I'm 12 and what is this?

```
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#menu li').hover(function(){
                $('.sublist').slideDown(200);
            });
        });
```

Comment: Is there a reason you're doing this with jQuery, rather than CSS (admittedly, I realise that IE 6 doesn't respect the `:hover` pseudo-element except for `a` elements)?

Comment: Further to above comment: [CSS method](http://jsbin.com/ekiyo4/), [jQuery method](http://jsbin.com/ekiyo4/2/).

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
$('#menu li').hover(function() {
  $(this).find('ul').stop(true, true).slideDown(200);
}, function() {
  $(this).find('ul').stop(true, true).slideUp(400);
});
```

Don't know if .sublist is ul though.

Comment: I'd suggest adding a second function to the `hover()`, to account for the `mouseout()` (or `mouseleave()`) event.

Comment: I know I'm late to the party, but you should add `.stop(true, true)` before the `.slideDown();` method to stop bubbling. Like so: `function(){$(this).find("ul").stop(true, true).slideDown(200);}`

Comment: @Ricardo It was 2 years ago, jQuery was cool. I've edited, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#menu li').hover(function(){
        $(this).find('ul.sublist').slideDown(200);
    },
    function(){
        $(this).find('ul.sublist').slideUp(200);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest:

```
$(document).ready(
  function(){
    $('li').has('ul').hover(
      function(){
        $(this).find('ul').show();
      },
      function(){
        $(this).find('ul').hide();
      });
  });
```

Using [`has()`](http://api.jquery.com/has/) (although you could, instead, use the [`:has()`](http://api.jquery.com/has-selector/) pseudo-selector) to identify the `li` elements with child `ul` elements.

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code:

```
// Dropdown toggle fuction
$('.dropdown-toggle').click(function(){
  $(this).next('.dropdown').slideToggle("fast");
});
//Hide dropdown on page click
$(document).on('click', function (e) {
    if(!$(".dropdown-toggle").is(e.target) && !$(".dropdown-toggle").has(e.target).length){
        $('.dropdown').slideUp("fast");
    }                       
});
```